# Font-Awesome scss compiling badly

Tags: sass, font-awesome

I imported font-awesome to a scss file. When I compile that scss file to css something goes wrong.

Instead of

```
.fa-sun-o:before {
  content: "\f185"; }
```

I see

```
.fa-sun-o:before {
  content: ""; }
```

How can I fix it? The compiler I use is Gulp-Sass